# mysql stored procedures limit of lines/characters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, text, carriage-return

once again I've run into a problem with mysql stored procedures.

It's a tricky one and I'll stupply some teest data.

Basically I have this load of text

Operation Manna  - Lancaster Series (7)
The 29th April sees the anniversary of one of the most unusual RAF Lancaster operations in WW2. The Netherlands was deep in what became known as the 'Hongerwinter' with food supplies almost non-existent due to military action and a very
 severe w

in

t

e

r
 - exacerbated by the deliberate breaching of some of the Dutch dykes. The RAF obtained acquiescence from the still occupying German Army, in April 1945,  to drop food supplies with a guarantee of safety for the supply aircraft - a minor miracle in its own right.

The first sortie was flown by a Canadian crew and over the next few days about  3,000 sorties dropped 7,000 tons of foodstuffs to the Dutch populace. The sorties were flown at low level (300 ft) and this composite image shows a section of Lancs en-route to the drop zone.

This image was posted on another forum and several Dutch colleagues noted that there were hardly any bulbs left in ‘45 for such a display, as they had all gone for foodstuffs.  I plead artistic licence and it is the only image I have (taken when we lived in the Netherlands in the ‘50s) that reflects the local countryside!

At the same time the Lancaster force started a massive airlift to return POWs from Germany (Operation Exodus).  Flying some 3,000 sorties the Lancasters repatriated around 75,000 prisoners - with up to 25 crammed into each Lanc - present day Health and Safety guys would just have loved that one!!

Truly - swords were being beaten into ploughshares

Composite of airshow images and a scanned old Kodachrome b/g - the last of the present Lancaster series..

and when I try and load it into a variable and insert it errors.
Now I know what you might say your variable is too small, well I use TEXT so I don't think it can be that.

It gets weirder see where I've returned around winter. Basically I entered those and it seems like the line returns are the problem!

Does anyone have a clue on how that works.
I've been trying various sections of the text and it seems the line returns are the problem, maybe.

Any ideas would be great.
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the string and insert and then update.
Insane

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar probelms, and it turned out to be an apostrophe ( ' ) in the text was making MySQL think it had reached the end of the text to be imported.  Check what field delimiters the db is using and make sure to either replace them or escape them in the text.

Comment: Yeah in the end I tried all over that and in the end I just split the string and inserted one bit at a time.
It's crazy!